# tcolorbox with option listings gives error if command used is already defined

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

Using the tcolorbox and its listing-feature I get with this code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\zB}{z.\,B.}
\begin{document}
% error message
\begin{tcblisting}{listing options = {style=tcblatex}}
   \newcommand{\zB}{z.\,B.}
\end{tcblisting}
%  no error message
%\begin{lstlisting}
%  \newcommand{\zB}{z.\,B.}
%\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

the error `Command \zB already defined`. Using the `lstlisting`-environment everything is working fine. I looked in the manual of `tcolorbox` but I failed how to avoid this error message.

Comment: well naturally. tcolorbox also typesets the code, and this means you are defining the command twice. If you want only a listing use `\begin{tcblisting}{listing options = {style=tcblatex}, listing only}`.

Comment: OK, manual p. 331, overlocked this item. Now its is working.